# Adding Category in WP_Query Not Working

Tags: wp-query, categories, query

Here's my query..

```
$params = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => 'product',
'orderby' => 'menu-order',
'order' => 'asc',
'fields' => 'ids',
//    'category_name' => 'stainless-steel-exhaust-ties',
'tax_query' =>
array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
     array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => 7)
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array( 'stainless-steel-exhaust-ties' )
    )
);
```

I've tried using `category_name` in the original params.. as well as and `AND` relation in the `tax_query`

Using `category_name` does not display any results... using the second tax_query just gives me all the results.

How do I filter by category in my `WP_Query`?

Comment: are you sure it's `category`? and not `cat` or `product_category`? Also can you indent correctly and place brackets on the correct lines? My initial reading of your code suggested you were missing out closing brackets

Comment: @brian use `product_cat` for woocommerce product category.

Comment: @maheshwaghmare thank you!  That at least worked without the `AND` relation.. will have to do some more testing to get that working.  But so relieving to actually get the category and not every single post everytime :)